# Show a hidden responsive div on hovering li elements relative to the position of li

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have list of images and on hovering each `li`, I need a `div` to show up near to the hovered element. I have tried to get the position of each `li` using **jquery**. But it didn't work. How can I establish this?

sample code :

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="image1.png"></li>
    <li><img src="image2.png"></li>
    <li><img src="image2.png"></li>
</ul>
<div class="popup-box hide">
    <p> some text...</p>
</div>

<style>
.hide{display:none;}
</style>
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle of your complete code for better understanding

Comment: I think want to show `tooltip` like view for the hidden div, for that you use, http://stevenbenner.github.io/jquery-powertip, this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this using the `mouseenter`, `mouseout` and `mousemove` events.

---

- On `mouseenter`, we shall show the div.
- On `mouseout`,  we shall hide the div.
- On `mousemove`, we shall change the position of the div on the fly.

---

```js
$("#list").on("mouseenter", "li", function() {

  $("#popupbox").show();

  $(this).off("mousemove").on('mousemove', function(e) {
    $('#popupbox').css({
      'top': e.pageY,
      'left': e.pageX,
      'z-index': '1'
    });
  });

}).on("mouseout", "li", function() {

  $("#popupbox").hide();

})
```

```css
li {
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.popup-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #00f;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li>
    <img src="image1.png">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="image2.png">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="image2.png">
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="popupbox" class="popup-box hide">
  <p>some text...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do it this way.

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
<div class="popup-box hide" style="position:absolute;">
    <p> some text...</p>
</div>

<style>
    .hide{display:none;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("ul li").on("mousemove", function(){
        var position = $(this).position(),
            popup = $(".popup-box");

        popup.removeClass("hide");
        popup.css({"top": position.top + "px", "left": position.left + "px"});
    })
    $("ul li").on("mouseout", function(){$(".popup-box").addClass("hide");})
</script>
```

I added style="position: absolute;" on your popup-box so it will follow the css position we're setting during mouse hover.

Hope this help